# How can I activate debug mode in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I am trying to activate the WordPress Debug mode but the error.log file is not created. I added this code to the wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem (Apache server). In the Apache server, inside the php.ini, the variable:

```
track_errors = Off
```

To get this information, you can do in a phpfile phpinfo();. So, to write the debug log file, you need to set track_errors as 'On'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Julien. There is no problem that file. the name of that is wp-config.php. I  typed incorrectly.

Comment: Ok, are you using an apache server for your wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cPanel for your server (which I'm assuming since you included the tag `cpanel` in your post), and the PHP-FPM is active, the wordpress error log goes to your site error log file, and won't appear in wp-content which is the wordpress default error log location.

Your site error log is located in

`/yourAccountName/logs/yourdomain_com.php.error.log`

Before 'your account name' you might see `/home/` or `/homexxx/` where xxx is some number.